# Point already added custom domain to app service Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, hosting, domain-name, custom-domain

I am trying to point this custom domain name to a service in GCP. I tried to see the docs but in all the docs there is a option to point to a service when you are adding a new custom domain. I don't have permissions to either delete or add a new domain. Where is the option to point this domain name to a service?

[image: Where is the option to point this domain name to a service]

Comment: You may want to check the `dispatch.yaml` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/dispatch-yaml

Answer (score 0):

To map subdomains you can use [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference/dispatch-yaml) file.

And then run $ gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml (it can be in any directory).

If you have example.com added under App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains for the default service, you can add the subdomain api.example.com for the other service. Later you need to add the new subdomain DNS records to your domain registrar as pointed out in the console configuration.